# Error when building new project - aapt finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

I am getting this error whenever I start new project:

> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
> matches the given name  'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>
> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'. C:\Users\prasid444\AndroidStudioProjects\Try1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\Users\prasid444\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Please help me fix this

Comment: upgrade your Android studio to latest version

Comment: if you have 1.5.1 or 2.0beta from Canary, try to choose from menu Build -> Rebuild

Comment: mine is 1.2.2 rebuild is not fixing this problem

Comment: what? Please upgrade to latest 1.5.1 - you're missing many fixed bugs and improved performance. And as I suppose your build-tools are newer than your AS version, which generates this problem

Comment: i've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

At first you go to `Build-> Clean Project`

and then go to `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Check also if you have the latest Android Studio version (1.5.1). Sometimes upgrade to newest unstable version by Canary Channel helps.

If you still want to use this Android Studio 1.2.x version please downgrade version of build-tools, targetSDK and support library. I'm pretty sure that Android SDK build-tools version is not fully compatible with your old 1.2.2 Android Studio version.

EDIT: That's definately problem with Android app resources, so if upgrade Android Studio and rebuilding the project still not resolve this problem, go to your app directory and delete `build` folders.